# When does a Google Cloud Messaging device group notification_key get deleted?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

The first thing I've found undocumented in the [device group docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications) is that, if you delete the only registration ID inside of a device group, the `notification_key` for that device group becomes deleted.

Therefore, when managing my device group registrations, I have to keep track of registration IDs that I've registered in my app that uses GCM. This way, I know whether or not to 'create' a group or 'add' to a group depending on whether or not that group has at least 1 registration ID. You would think Google wouldn't impose this sort of behavior (why can't their API figure out whether to do an `add` or `create` operation), but it is what it is.

My question is, when else can a `notification_key` get deleted? One scenario I see would be a user on 1 device who gets a second GCM registration ID after > ~6 months of app usage. Let's say their GCM registration ID was `123abc` when they first used the app, and now their GCM registration ID is `456xyz`. If the user goes to logout, I will remove `456xyz` from the device group. But do I have to bother removing `123abc` from the device group? And if I don't, will the device group / `notification_key` remain active?

Another scenario would be if the user uninstalls the app and then comes back a few days later. When the app is uninstalled, the GCM registration ID that was added to the device group would be invalid - I believe they are unique across actual app installs. So is there any chance that the `notification_key` would be deleted before the user reinstalls the app and attempts to rejoin the presumed existing device group / `notification_key'?